# Searching for a FAST and THREADSAFE Database for large amount of data

Tags: php, c++, python, c

Hey, searching for a database like the titel.

I need it in many threads and if possible scaleable so it could run an several server...

It should be possible to acess the db from c/c++ and python maybe from php...

Comment: Can you define "scaleable" (sic)? Read scale? Write scale? What is a large amount of data, how will you be searching it?

Comment: read and write scale. the amount i could calculate is >500gb < 1tb

Answer (score 2):

Most people start with:

http://www.mysql.com/

Comment: And never forgive themselves for it

Comment: @A A: Granted it's a VERY subjective (borderline trollish) statement, but if you are interested in the grievances people have with MySQL, you could start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332194/is-mysql-really-this-bad) and follow the various links from there.